# Adding User to Organization Unit and Group using Google Apps Provisioning API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-provisioning-api

I have done coding in .Net to create google account using Google Apps Provisioning API. I am successful in creating Google Account but I am not being able to add user to particular Organization Unit and Group. I have achieved the goal of account creation like this:

```
//Creating Google Account

 AppsService appService = new AppsService("Mydomain", "AdminUsername", "AdminPassword");

         try
                {

                var account = appService.CreateUser(googleEmail, FirstName.Text, LastName.Text, password);

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ResultsLabel.Text += "<br />Can't create this Google Account";
                }
```

After user is added, it gets created under main domain "Users" in Google. But I have to put that user into the Organization unit where they belong to, here in my case, I need to put the user into "Staff" Organization Unit. I am not sure what applicationName means, I am just using the project solution name or am I not using correct name here? What does applicatinName mean, and what should I use? I am using CustomerID as "GoogleCustomerId" in following code that I got from Google for our domain. I have done coding like this which doesn't work for adding user to Organization Unit:

```
//Adding User to Organization Unit


                OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("mydomain", "applicationName");

                service.setUserCredentials("AdminUsername", "AdminPassword");

                service.UpdateOrganizationUser("GoogleCustomerId", Email.Text, "Staff", "Users");
```

I get this exception with the above code to add user to Organization Unit:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Execution of request failed: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C090ll5hh/Test@domain.com
  Source=Google.GData.Client
  ResponseString=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1801" invalidInput="" reason="InvalidValue" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>
```

Here is my code to add user to Group but it is also not working, I need to add user to staff@mydomain.com group:

```
//Adding User to Group


   service.Groups.AddMemberToGroup("staff@mydomain.com", username);
```

Any idea on this one please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research and making change in code adding to Organization Unit and Group is now working. I have to put "/" for "String oldOrgUnitPath" as it is the top organization unit where user is initially added.

//Adding User to Organization Unit

```
            OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("mydomain", "applicationName");

            service.setUserCredentials("AdminUsername", "AdminPassword");

            service.UpdateOrganizationUser("GoogleCustomerId", Email.Text, "Staff", "/");
```

To make adding to group work I have to make this change in code. We shouldn't use @domain.com with group name and switching the position of Email id and group name worked.

```
//Adding User to Group

   service.Groups.AddMemberToGroup(Email.Text, "Staff");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to Google, this API is about to stop working in the end of April, 2015.

I've had a couple of problems with this API since last year and I have decided to take a look at the "new" API instead: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/

Even if you solved this problem for now, I would recommend you to do check the new API if you want your application to run smoothly in the future.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion VicTheMagician. I should look at it soon, but how is the implementation of SDK? Is it same to Google Apps Provisioning API?

Comment: There is some differences between them regarding the implementation. In the new one, you have to add all of the classes you want through NuGet Manager in Visual Studio. And then you can refer to them in the code ("using Google.Apis;" for example).